# Android, fragment listview onItemclick / onitemselect issues

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, onitemclicklistener

**My problem:** I have main class and 3 fragments controlled using swipe (`SectionsPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`).

On all of the fragments we use listview to generate list with data from SQLite. This works fine however the onItemclick methods do not work - We have tried several approaches without success.

We use custom simpleCursorAdaptor and set the view via getView method of Adaptor. Again this works just fine. We get nice tablerows with the content from the DB.

Does anybody have an example we can look at to fix our issues? Example without ListFragment.

Some of our code looks like this:

```
    public class TranssaktionFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener

    listview.setAdapter(transsaktionadaptor);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        private String TAG;
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, "*****************************Clicked************************* "  );                             
        }
    });
```

Comment: is it possible that the click listener is being called but because you have a `null` TAG is not showing in the LogCat? I'm just wondering, because the rest of the code seems fine to me.

Comment: I see that - we also tried with a toast - no diff. The method is not being called for some reason

Comment: Do you have views like `Buttons`, `CheckBoxes` in the row layout? If yes, did you make them non focusable?

Comment: so far only textviews - did not make them nonfocus..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, **onItemClick** didn't called. There is a Relativelayout with an Image in the custom ListRow. I've added  `android:focusable="false"` to the Relativelayout and now it works again. I'm wondering why but it works. Thanks to **Luksprog**!!